# "seit ein[em] Jahr"

Tags: dative, numbers

The phrase "seit einem Jahr", means "for a year", correct ?

Assume I want to say "for one year", where *one* is a numerical pronoun (as "zwei" in "seit zwei Jahren"), and **not** an article as in "seit einem Jahr".

So, in this case, can I use *"seit ein Jahr"*, or not?

Comment: NB: "For a year" only in the sense of "since one year ago". Ich lerne seit einem Jahr Deutsch = I've been learning German for a year. (I still do.)

Comment: "Einem" in "seit einem Jahr" is not an article.

Comment: Note, that *seit* implies the process started in the past and reaches the current time. For the future or the more distant past you would use *für* as in *Ich gehe für ein Jahr nach Australien*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some numbers follow declensions as well, and the numeral to **1**, *eins*, follows that of the article *ein*. Then numerals differing from it have also their less irregular declension forms, as shown [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:elf).

Comment: Following this rule, translation of "I have only one dog", would be "Ich habe nur einen Hund", while "I have only two dogs" is "Ich habe nur zwei Hunde", Could you please confirm this is correct.

Comment: @kiruwka Richtig.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot say

> <s>Seit ein Jahr</s>

*Seit* is a preposition that forces the **dative** and the dative of "ein" is "einem".

You need to say

> seit einem Jahr

"ein" is an exception in the declension of numerals - Even as a numeral, its declension follows that of the article "ein", *when it is used in front of a substantive and not preceeded by a definite article*.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that example in my question. in this case "ein" is an article, so in dative it becomes einem. That is clear. However, can it be a pronomen, like " one, zwei, drei, etc". And we don't decline "two" in "seit zwei Jahren", do we ?

Comment: "ein" is an exception in the declension of numerals - Even as a numeral, its declension follows that of the article "ein", *when it is used in front of a substantive and not preceeded by a definite article*.

Comment: Why is it not declined in this sentence then : "  seit ein und einem halben Jahr" ? Or this is also incorrect

Comment: A native speaker would say "seit eineinhalb Jahren". That said, it's "seit einem Jahr" but "seit zwei, drei, fünf, zehn, .... Jahren".

Answer (score 1):

Both, the indefinite article »a« and the numeral »one« translate to »ein« in German. In German you only can tell from the context if »ein« (or its declined forms) is an article or a numeral.

- **Nominative case**

  - **masculine**

    > ***Article:***
    >   Ich habe den Täter nicht genau gesehen, aber ich bin sicher: Es war **ein Mann.**
    >   I didn't see the offender exactly, but I am sure: It was **a man.**
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   Sieben Menschen saßen im Bus: Sechs Frauen und **ein Mann.**
    >   There was seven people sitting in the bus: Six women and **one man.**
  - **feminine**

    > ***Article:***
    >   ... Es war **eine Frau.**
    >   ... It was **a woman.**
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   ... Sechs Männer und **eine Frau.**
    >   ... Six men and **one woman.**
  - **neuter**

    > ***Article:***
    >   ... Es war **ein Kind.**
    >   ... It was **a child.**
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   ... Sechs Erwachsene und **ein Kind.**
    >   ... Six adults and **one child.**
- **Genitive case**

  - **masculine**

    > ***Article:***
    >   Dies ist die Welt **eines Mannes.**
    >   This is **a man's** world.
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   Dies ist die Show **eines Mannes.**
    >   This is **one man's** show.
  - **feminine**

    > ***Article:***
    >   Dies ist die Welt **einer Frau.**
    >   This is **a woman's** world.
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   Dies ist die Show **einer Frau.**
    >   This is **one woman's** show.
  - **neuter**

    > ***Article:***
    >   Dies ist die Welt **eines Kindes.**
    >   This is **a child's** world.
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   Dies ist die Show **eines Kindes.**
    >   This is **one childs's** show.
- **Dative case**

  - **masculine**

    > ***Article:***
    >   So etwas fällt nur **einem Mann** ein.
    >   Such a thing comes to mind only to **a man.**
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   Das ist streng geheim. Wenn du das auch nur **einem Mann** sagst, war alles umsonst. 
    >   This is top secret. If you tell it only **one man**, then all was in vein.
  - **feminine**

    > ***Article:***
    >   So etwas fällt nur **einer Frau** ein.
    >   Such a thing comes to mind only to **a woman.**
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   ... Wenn du das auch nur **einer Frau** sagst, ...
    >   ... If you tell it only **one woman**, ...
  - **neuter**

    > ***Article:***
    >   So etwas fällt nur **einem Kind** ein.
    >   Such a thing comes to mind only to **a child.**
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   ... Wenn du das auch nur **einem Kind** sagst, ...
    >   ... If you tell it only **one child**, ...
- **Accusative case**

  - **masculine**

    > ***Article:***
    >   Diese Silhouette ist unscharf, aber ich sehe darin **einen Mann.**
    >   This silhouette is out of focus, but I see **a man** in it.
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   Du irrst dich. Vor der Tür stehen nicht drei Männer. Ich sehe nur **einen Mann.**
    >   You are wrong. There are not three men standing in front of the door. I see only **one man.**
  - **feminine**

    > ***Article:***
    >   ... ich sehe darin **eine Frau.**
    >   ... I see **a woman** in it.
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   ... Ich sehe nur **eine Frau.**
    >   ... I see only **one woman.**
  - **neuter**

    > ***Article:***
    >   ... ich sehe darin **ein Kind.**
    >   ... I see **a child** in it.
    >   ***Numeral:***
    >   ... Ich sehe nur **ein Kind.**
    >   ... I see only **one child.**